# Total points isnt shown in terminal

Tags: dart

> ```
> import 'dart:io';
>
> void main() {
>   String? Subject;
>   int Total = 0;
>   String? Math = "Math";
>   String? History = "History";
>   String? Geography = "Geography";
>   String? Azerbaijani = "Azerbaijani";
>   String? English = "English";
>   int AllQuestions;
>   int Wrong;
>   print("Let's calculate your balls");
>
>   print("Choose the subject");
>   Subject = stdin.readLineSync();
>   print("Enter the number of questions");
>   AllQuestions = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
>   print("Enter the number of wrong questions");
>   Wrong = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
>
>   if (Subject == Math) {
>     Total = Total + (AllQuestions - Wrong) * 8;
>     print(Total);
>   };
>
>   print("Choose the subject");
>   Subject = stdin.readLineSync();
>   print("Enter the number of questions");
>   AllQuestions = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
>   print("Enter the number of wrong questions");
>   Wrong = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
>
>   if (Subject == History) {
>     Total = Total + ((AllQuestions - Wrong) * 4);
>     print(Total);
>   } ;
>
>   print("Choose the subject");
>   Subject = stdin.readLineSync();
>   print("Enter the number of questions");
>   AllQuestions = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
>   print("Enter the number of wrong questions");
>   Wrong = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
>
>   if (Subject == Geography) {
>     Total = Total + (AllQuestions - Wrong) * 8;
>     print(Total);
>   } ;
>
>   print("Choose the subject");
>   Subject = stdin.readLineSync();
>   print("Enter the number of questions");
>   AllQuestions = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
>   print("Enter the number of wrong questions");
>   Wrong = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
>
>   if (Subject == Azerbaijani) {
>     Total = Total + (AllQuestions - Wrong) * 4;
>     print(Total);
>   };
>   
>   print("Choose the subject");
>   Subject = stdin.readLineSync();
>   print("Enter the number of questions");
>   AllQuestions = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
>   print("Enter the number of wrong questions");
>   Wrong = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
>
>   if (Subject == English) {
>     Total = Total + ((AllQuestions - Wrong) * 4);
>     print(Total);
>   };
>   print("Congrats!");
> }
> ```

```
With this one I count the points of each subject. For exm, if I got out of 25 questions only 5 wrong answer, it will be 25-5= 20*8=160
```

And terminal looks like: Choose the subject: Math; Enter the number of question: 25; Enter the number of wrong questions: 5, Total 160. It works, but then I tried to short this code.

> ```
> import 'dart:io';
>
> void main() {
>   String? Subject;
>   int Total = 0;
>   String? Math ;
>   String? History ;
>   String? Geography;
>   String? Azerbaijani;
>   String? English;
>   int AllQuestions = 0;
>   int Wrong = 0;
>   int Meaning = 0;
> ```

> ```
>   inputsD(Subject, AllQuestions, Wrong,Total);
>
>   if (Subject == "Math") {
>     inputsName(Subject, AllQuestions, Wrong, Total, 8);
>   } 
>   ;
> inputsD(Subject, AllQuestions, Wrong,Total);
>   if (Subject == "History") {
>      inputsName(Subject, AllQuestions, Wrong, Total, 4);
>   } 
>   ;
> inputsD(Subject, AllQuestions, Wrong,Total);
>   if (Subject == "Geography") {
>     inputsName(Subject, AllQuestions, Wrong, Total, 8);
>   } 
>   ;
> inputsD(Subject, AllQuestions, Wrong,Total);
>   if (Subject == "Azerbaijani") {
>      inputsName(Subject, AllQuestions, Wrong, Total, 4);
>   } 
>   ;
> inputsD(Subject, AllQuestions, Wrong,Total);
>   if (Subject == "English") {
>      inputsName(Subject, AllQuestions, Wrong, Total, 4);
>   } 
>   ;
> }
>
> void inputsName(Subject, AllQuestions, Wrong, Total, Meaning) {
>   Total = Total + ((AllQuestions - Wrong) * Meaning());
>     print(Total);
> }
> void inputsD(Subject, AllQuestions, Wrong, Total){
>   print("Choose the subject");
>   Subject = stdin.readLineSync();
>   print("Enter the number of questions");
>   AllQuestions = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
>   print("Enter the number of wrong questions");
>   Wrong = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);}
> ```

It does not show total point of each subject. What is wrong and how I can fix it? It just asks about subject, al questions and wrong questions, but doesnt show the total point.